# get buckets count in elasticsearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to search a database with a lot of duplicates.
I am using field colapse and it works, however it returns the amount of hits (including duplicates) and not the amount of buckets.

```
"aggs": {
        "uniques": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "guid"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "jobs": { "top_hits": { "_source": "title", "size": 1 }}  
            }
        }
    }
```

I can count the buckets by making another request using cardinality (but it only returns count, not the documents):

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "uniques" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "guid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return both requests (buckets + total bucket count) in one search?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can combine both of these aggregations into 1 request.

```
{
   "aggs" : {
    "uniques" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "guid"
        }
    },
    "uniquesTerms": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "guid"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "jobs": { "top_hits": { "_source": "title", "size": 1 }}  
        }
    }
}
```